# How to change scale of units in OpenOffice

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I have made a chart in OpenOffice but in x-axis the values are very small ~10^-3. How can I just change the numbers so that they are scaled without changing the data?

Here's a picture of the x-axis:

[image: http://imgur.com/hvnNfZK.]

I want all the numbers be multiplied with 1000 so that it would be like this:
2.8 2.9 3.0 etc

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: You need to use a "helper column" which is a copy of the data multiplied by `1000` and use the helper column for the x data.

Comment: And how exactly can I do that?

Comment: Insert a new column which is a copy of the x values multiplied by 1000, use that new column for the x-axis.